# Blender cycles glass from sideview not transparent at all

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

[image]

From top view glass looks like glass but from side view It looks like this:[image]

So, why its not transparent and how I can make it transparent ?

Comment: please post a screenshot of your material node setup or your [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: its just a simple glass shader Color: white IOR: 1.45 and roughness 0

Comment: Could you please post your .blend file?

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=407" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/407/)

Comment: I think your actual problem here is that when you look at a plate from its side, it's mostly the reflection (due to fresnel), and your "sky" is grey. So it is realistic, you just have no environment to reflect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your [normals](https://www.blender.org/manual/glossary/index.html?highlight=face%20normal#term-face-normal) are facing the wrong way - press <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd> in edit mode (with everything selected) to recalculate them.

How they were before (wrong):

[image: wrong]

After recalculating:

[image: right]

The reason the glass looks bad with inverted normals is because glass uses a fresnel function to calculate where the most reflections should be:

[image: fresnel]

[image: glass]

<sup>(both spheres use exactly the same material)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

In Cycles the glass shader works better if it has some thickness.

In this case a simple solidify modifier at top of the stack takes care of things:

[image]

Comment: Their mesh already appears to have thickness, so this would make it a hollow plate..